# Search for a Word Occuring After A Non-Alphanumeric Symbol

Tags: regex, python-3.x

So I would like to re-implement todo.txt in python as a learning project. Now, I would like (for testing) that if I would add say Ask a Question on SO +StackOverFlow, I would like to reprint +StackOverflow (NOT Ask a Question on SO +StackOverflow, since Regular Expressions are the hard part, the rest is cream cheese (the rest of the owl).

I have tried to use \W for this, but all Python gives me is [].

```
import re
todo = input("")
plusregex = re.findall("\W +", todo)
print(plusregex)
```

Thank you for everything SO community!

Comment: You should either use lookbehind or capture groups (which are more flexible).

Comment: If you are trying to extract the "tags" maybe the regular expression `\+[^\s]+` would help? (A literal plus followed by anything but whitespace repeating)

Comment: `re.findall(r"\w+", todo)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression `[^\w\s]\w+` would do the trick to capture words starting with non-alphanumeric characters:

```
import re
todo = "Ask a Question on SO +StackOverFlow +test"
plusregex = re.findall("[^\w\s]\w+", todo)
print(plusregex)
```

which outputs: `['+StackOverFlow', '@python', '!test']`